# Connect to MySql over Airport Wireless LAN

Tags: airport, mac-mini, network, mysql

I have installed MySql on a Mac Mini that I want to use as a dev database server. I have created a toy database on the server. I have created a wireless network using Airport. I now want to connect to the database from a MySql client on my Macbook Air. I am using the root user with no security at all (hey, it's a toy database), but cannot connect as the Macbook is not allowed to connect.

What do I need to do to configure my WLAN so that the client can see the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open terminal.
2. Type `ifconfig`
3. Find something like `inet 192.168.1.100 netmask`
4. `192.168.1.100` is local ip of your machine in your WLAN. You can connect to mysql using this ip.

Comment: afraid this doesn't work. I try to connect using the MySql using the Workbench GUI and get the error Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 10.0.1.5:3306:
  Host '10.0.1.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
I this because the IP is created dynamically (by Airport)?

Comment: This is not WLAN problem. Your mysql server doen't allow non-local connecetions. Read this (http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/) article to configure your server.